# Installing RGtk2 package in R

Tags: r, rattle

Can you please help me with installing RGtk2 package in R?

I tried the following:

> install.packages("RGtk2")
> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/filip/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> Warning message:
> package ‘RGtk2’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

> install.packages("RGtk2", depen=T, type="source")
> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/filip/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> Warning message:
> package ‘RGtk2’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Then I tried to install it from archive, but I got:

install.packages("C:/Users/filip/Downloads/RGtk2_2.20.36.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/filip/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
package ‘RGtk2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

> library(RGtk2)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RGtk2’:
> package ‘RGtk2’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it

Can you please help me?

Comment: a solution to your problem may likely be found here: https://gist.github.com/sebkopf/9405675

Comment: LATEST NEWS: RGtk2 Retired From CRAN December 2021. Note the dates. The citation immediately above is 5 years old and unlikely to be of much help. What we should be asking is "why" this seems necessary.

Comment: A lot of the net traffic on RGtk2 relates to its requirement by Rattle. If that's the case then go here: https://rattle.togaware.com/

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that the link they are providing "https://access.togaware.com/RGtk2_2.20.36.2.zip" is not working